# Run a SQL Server Agent Job using Microsoft Access or when I get an Email

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, outlook, ssms, sql-agent-job

I have a process where the user goes into an Access database and processes data and when that is finished, the Access process sends an Outlook email to me every time. Is there a way that the Access database can kick off a SQL Server Agent Job or when I get that Outlook email, I can trigger the job?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use VBA in the access database to kick off the sql server agent job. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137302/excel-vba-executing-a-job-within-sql-server-via-a-macro) is for excel, but it should port to Access VBA just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Call runStoredProcfromAccess
End Sub

Sub runStoredProcfromAccess()
   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, RS As New ADODB.Recordset, strSql As String
   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

   cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=your_server_name;Database=your_database_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
   cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cmd.CommandText = "dbo.CustOrderHist"
   cmd.Parameters("@CustomerID").Value = "ALFKI"
   Set RS = cmd.Execute
   Debug.Print RS(0)
   RS.Close
   cmd.ActiveConnection.Close
End Sub
```